Keep Element Inside Viewport
I want to show "tooltips", for dfns, positioned to the right and above each respective dfn element.
I'm using dfn[title]:hover::after with content: attr(title) to show big, custom pseudo-element
The problem is, sometimes those positioned elements appear outside the viewport. This is bad because the user has to scroll to read them. Instead, I want the tooltips constrained to the viewport. That is, each tooltip should be positioned as specified, but if it would appear outside the viewport, it should be repositioned to be just inside the viewport.
I also have a fade-in effect using a CSS transition, as shown.


dfn[title] {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

dfn[title]::after {
  opacity: 0.0000000001;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  padding: .5em .46em .5em .5em;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #F3F3F3;
  font-size: smaller;
  border-radius: .4em;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  content: attr(title);
  z-index: -1;
}

abbr[title]:hover::after,
dfn[title]:hover::after {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.9999999;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tooltip</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    This rodent study showed that the <dfn title="Alpha-53-Thr mutation: point mutation in the human alpha-synuclein (α-synuclein) gene, associated with early-onset familial PD">A53T</dfn> and <dfn title="a point mutation in the alpha-synuclein (SNCA) gene, which is associated with autosomal dominant Parkinson’s disease">A30P</dfn>    genetic mutations in α-synuclein have increased propensity to aggregate compared with the wild-type protein, and this strongly supports the direct and critical role of α-synuclein aggregation in the etiology of Parkinson’s disease. <dfn title="a point mutation in the alpha-synuclein (SNCA) gene, which is associated with autosomal dominant Parkinson’s disease">A30P</dfn>
  </p>
  <p>
    s<a href="https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/bi010616g" target="_blank">Effect of Familial Parkinson's Disease Point Mutations <dfn title="a point mutation in the alpha-synuclein (SNCA) gene, which is associated with autosomal dominant Parkinson’s disease">A30P</dfn> and <dfn title="Alpha-53-Thr mutation: point mutation in the human alpha-synuclein (α-synuclein) gene, associated with early-onset familial PD">A53T</dfn> on the Structural Properties, Aggregation, and Fibrillation of Human α-Synuclein</a>,
    Jie Li, et al.
  </p>
</body>



How can I achieve this effect with CSS only?
Also, in the live document, there will be additional structure of other elements (SECTION, LI, etc) ancestral to the DFN elements.

It's 2024 now - so I might suggest CSS Anchor Positioning.  (It has a neat feature controlled by the @position-try directive, which configures the element to stay within the viewport)
